# Difficulty with Database Connection in Python Flask - Getting 'OperationalError: unable to open database file' Error

Tags: python, database, flask, database-connection, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a Python Flask project where I'm facing challenges with establishing a database connection. I've set up my Flask application to use SQLite as the database backend. However, when attempting to execute the application, I encounter the following error:

[image]

I've checked my database configuration, ensured that the file path is correct, and verified that the necessary permissions are in place. Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Here's a snippet of my Flask app configuration related to the database:

[image]

Could someone please provide insights into what might be causing this 'OperationalError' and suggest a possible solution? I'm relatively new to Flask and database connections.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)